# Probabilities of cases that are interdependent in a non-trivial way

Tags: probability, statistics

I have a probability calculation which I hope someone can give advice on. I have a network with two routes in which I can send bits.

The first route consists of a single channel, with probability of transfer $p$. The first route can transfer a bit without any other requirements.

The second route consists of four channels, each with transfer probability $p$. They must all succeed for a bit to be transferred **AND the channel from the first route must also succeed.**

My first thought was that the number of bits, $n$ was simple given by

$$ n = p + p^5$$

however now I'm wondering I need to account for the dependence of the two channels on each other, but I'm not sure how to go about implementing this.

Thanks in advance to anyone who can help

Comment: You didn't mention any dependence.  That would obviously change the problem dramatically.  Assuming independence (which I expect is what is intended) then the answer is the product $p\times p^4=p^5$.  If you want some dependence between the various gates then the problem can't be answered without information regarding that dependence.

Comment: I want to know the total number of bits though which is obvious two if both channels transfer a bit. That's why I thought I should add the probabilities but this doesn't take into account the fact that the second channel requires the first to succeed

Comment: No idea what "the total number of bits" means here.  If the gates are all independent (as, surely, you intend) then the answer is $p^5$ since you need all five gates to be open.

Comment: You can express the dependence: $P(\texttt{succeed channel 1})\cdot P(\texttt{succeed channel 2-5|succeed channel 1})=p\cdot p^4=p^5$

Comment: @Lulu I have two channels, I can send one bit through each, I want to know the total number of bits I can successfully receive in terms of the probability.

Comment: @callculus thanks for the response, what does 2-5|succeed mean?

Comment: @Lulu I think you're right about the probability of receiving both bits, being $p^5$, but what about the probability that only the single channel succeeds? There is a chance of receiving only one bit or two bits (with probability $p^5$)

Comment: @Wilky94 You seem to be changing the problem.  If you intended a different problem then what you wrote, you should edit your post to reflect the correction.

Comment: @Wilky94  To be clear:  you said that transmission required that both channels work.  Given that, it makes no sense to split your message up between the channels.  If you meant something other than what you wrote, please clarify.

Comment: @Lulu Sorry for the confusion, only the second path requires both routes to work

Comment: Not following.  Please edit the original post to reflect what you actually intended.

Comment: I have now updated the post

Comment: @Wilky94 $P(\texttt{succeed channel 2-5|succeed channel 1})$ is a conditional probability. It means the probability that channel 2-5 are succeeded, given that channel 1 has been succeeded.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, that's clear now.  In that case:  if you send a single bit through both channels then the probability it gets through is $p+p^4-p^5$.  Your sum double counts the scenarios in which it gets through on both channels.

Comment: As a sanity check note that $0≤p+p^4-p^5≤1$ for $p\in [0,1]$.

Comment: @Lulu Thanks, that makes sense. What would happen if I sent different bits through both channels, so that I send two bits, but the dependence is still there?

Comment: What probability do you want to compute in that case?  You get the first bit through with probability $p(b_1)=p$.  You get both bits through with probability $p^5$.

Comment: @Lulu Ideally what I want is a formula for the number of bits transferred for a given probability. The result would be a curve with 0 bits for probability 0 and 2 bits for probability 1

Comment: Not following.  Can you use my last comment to answer you question?  Note that my $p(b_1)$ is NOT the probability that only one bit goes through.  Rather, it is the probability that the specified bit $b_1$ goes through.  Since the probability that both go through is $p^5$ we see that the probability that only $b_1$ makes it is $p-p^5$.